# Most efficient/performant way to store large images and metadata in tiff format

Tags: c#, .net, tiff

I have a requirement to save ~1-5 tiff images with a maximum size of roughly 10MB each.  Each file will have it's own metadata file which contains serialized classes.  I also need to house another XML file for quick access to important data about the file (potentially to search and sort the images and tell the software how to interact with the image).

What would be the most efficient and fastest to load/save all this data?

I was thinking possibly using a multi-paged tiff file where each page has it's own metadata file and xml file, the problem being that would be one huge tiff file and possibly very slow to load and save.

Would it be better to separate the metadata and xml from the file itself?  If so then I could possibly combine the metadata and xml files.  Or should I not use a multi-page tiff and create multiple tiff files in a folder structure?

Any help appreciated...